# Pandas python dataframe: count the time in which the number is missing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have e dataframe like this:

[image]

The number 12 is present in first position. If i ask: how long has the number 12 is missing from the dataframe, after August 1, 2016?. The answer should be: 4 times. How you could do using pandas?

Comment: Can you show your expected output? Or you just want a number `4`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) for replace all values to `NaN` if condition `False` with [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.last_valid_index.html) for find last value by condition in column. Then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) values from last non `NaN` index to the end and get `length` of `DataFrame`, also need substract `1` because it select also last valid row:

```
s = df.NumberOne.where(df.NumberOne == 12)
print (s)
0    12.0
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
Name: NumberOne, dtype: float64

print (s.last_valid_index())
0

print (len(df.loc[s.last_valid_index():]) - 1)
4
```